# Why is view with Row_Number much slower

Tags: sql, sql-server, view

I have a query with several cross joins and without filtering, it ends up with several tens of million records, but with the correct filtering, I get typically between 200 and 1000 records. This is no problem as long I run the query, but If a create a view of it and apply the filter on the view, the query just times out.( more then 30 seconds)

But this is only a problem if I use `ROW_number` with partition grouping in the view, if I remove this from the view, its no problem. ( I also use this in the query, exact same query as in the view)

I guess this is because `Row_number` is counting on everything in the view before the "where" filter is applied, but if I run the exact same command with filter, but not as a view, the response is less then a second.

My understanding of views are they will combine the query in the view with the query from when you are calling the view:-

```
select * from view where id = 100
```

will be translate into

```
select * from tableCreatedWievFrom where Id = 100
```

So why is there a difference?

Comment: Can you post query plans?

Comment: you may need index on the partition field